# add record in SQL based on last character of a field

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a field in sql that contains a 1 or 0 at the end. What I am trying to do is if the field has a 1 at the end but no corresponding 0 I would like to add that record.

3 different examples

Field value

- Data1 ( I would like to add another record containing Data0)
- Data0 ( I would like to add another record containing Data1)
- Data0 and Data1 both exists in table ( Do nothing )

Comment: Those rows are related with another column or you'll have just two rows in the table?

Comment: Oooh my g… how many [NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms) are you breaking at once?

Comment: do the rows have a fixed length?

Comment: All the other columns will be different. There are a total of 6 columns. Description and 5 accums. The description column is not fixed length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into test(col, another_column_1,...,another_column_n)
select substr(col,1, length(col)-1) ||   --this is the base value
        max(mod(substr(col,length(col),length(col))+1,2)) --this is the termination (0 or 1)
        as col ,
        max(another_column_1),
        ...
        max(another_column_n)
from test
where substr(col,length(col),length(col)) between '0' and '1'
group by substr(col,1, length(col)-1)
having count(*)=1;
```

you can see test [here](http://sqlize.com/u584Rm4gzI)

*Updated for Oracle*

Comment: It is giving me a not enough values error. I should have mentioned before I'm doing this in Oracle

Comment: it is ok for oracle, but you should use substr instead. and you should insert the other columns. I'll update the answer in seconds.

Comment: Ok this is what I have insert into best_plan_totals(description) select substr(description,1, length(description)-1) || max(mod(substr(description,length(description),length(description))+1,2)) as description from best_plan_totals group by substr(description,1, length(description)-1) having count(*)=1

Comment: you have some descriptions not ending in 0/1?

Comment: Yes I do. With those values I don't want anything to happen

Comment: ok, these rows must be excluded, as I did in the updated answer. See WHERE clause

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much. Best site ever

Comment: If this done fine what you want, you may accept the answer. (This increase some of your scores, and some of mine.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can use the `LIKE` operator.

You can do something like:

```
(field like '%1' or field like '%0') and not field like '%0%1'
```

But generally, SQL is not suitable for text processing. This `LIKE` thing is pretty much the most advanced text processing feature in SQL.

Comment: This resulted in returning every row

Comment: I'm basically trying to have 2 records for each unique description field. One with a 1 at the end and the other with a 0 at the end

Comment: This query shouldn't return rows where the field looks like "abc0abc1".